# How to get all the yyyymm dates between two dates which are in yyyymm format in SAS?

Tags: date, sas

I have two different dates 201509 and 201608. I want to get all the dates between them in the format yyyymm like (201509,201510,201511,201512,201601,201602,201603,201604,201605,201606,201607,201608). The issue is tackling the months between years. ALso, teh months keep changing and it might be just 201601 to 201612. It's a daily run code and I'm trying to automate it in SAS. Any help appreciated!

Comment: They are actual date numeric variables, or are character variables?

Comment: Date format numeric variables

Answer (score 3):

SAS has functions that allow you to do this easily but you must first convert/read your dates as "SAS Dates".  Then you can use INTCK to count the months between start and end and INTNX to create the new month date values.

```
data months;
   input (start end)(:yymmn.);
   format start end yymm.;
   do i = 0 to intck('month',start,end);
      month = intnx('month',start,i);
      output;
      end;
   format month yymm.;
   cards;
 201509 201608
 ;;;; 
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're date format already then add a day onto the interval and it can be as simple as

```
where date between '01Jan2016'd and '31Dec2016'd;
```

If you can't figure out the logic each day, you can create macro variables that will do it for you.

```
%let start=201601;
%let end=201612;
%let start_date = %sysfunc(inputn(&start, yymmn6.), date9.);
%let end_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(inputn(&end, yymmn6.)), 0, end), date9.);
%put &start_date.;
%put &end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic is below.

```
   For intY = intStartYear To intEndYear
      If intY = Value(intEndYear) Then intZ = Value(intEndMonth) Else intZ = 12
      For intX = intStartMonth To intZ
         If intX < 10 Then
            Print intY & "0" & intX
         Else
            Print intY & intX
         End If
      Next intX
      intStartMonth = 1
   Next intY
```